# How to reference many-to-one association in Doctrine 2 by a non-primary key

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, many-to-one

As I understand, Doctrine requires **many-to-one** associations to **reference the primary key** on the one side. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537745/doctrine2-undefined-index-many-to-one-with-non-default-referencedcolumnname-d#comment17425530_12662074) or [here](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/452#issuecomment-9185156))

How would one solve a many-to-one association referenced by an unique key in a Doctrine 2?

In the following I am showing, what I have come up with so far and ran into to above referenced issue. What changes have to be made to get it working in my context?

In my case:

A project has among other properties a `snapshotId` and `cid`. The `cid` represents an internal project number. On certain changes a snapshot is taken and persisted with a unique `snapshotId` (including all dependent entries in associated table - not shown here). The entry with an empty (null) snapshotId is the current state.

Changes on a project are being tracked in `ProjectHistory`. For the purpose of demonstration this entity has the properties `function`, `modifyDate` and `modifyUserId`.

The Project has a one-to-many association to ProjectHistory. The ProjectHistory a many-to-one association to Project. The former is working as expected, the latter brings the error referred to in the beginning.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     indexes={
 *         @ORM\Index(
 *             name="cid",
 *             columns={"cid"}
 *         ),
 *     },
 *     uniqueConstraints={
 *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(
 *             name="unique_snapshot_per_project",
 *             columns={"snapshot_id", "cid"}
 *         ),
 *     },
 * )
 */
class Project
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @var string
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid", unique=true, nullable=true)
     * @var string|null
     */
    private $snapshotId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column()
     * @var string
     */
    private $cid;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProjectHistory", mappedBy="projectCid", cascade={"persist"})
     * @var Collection|ProjectHistory[]
     */
    private $projectHistories;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->projectHistories = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function toArray(): array
    {
        return [
            'id'               => $this->getId(),
            'snapshotId'       => $this->getSnapshotId(),
            'cid'              => $this->getCid(),
            'projectHistories' => $this->getProjectHistoriesAsArray(),
        ];
    }

    public function getProjectHistoriesAsArray(): array
    {
        $projectHistories = [];
        foreach ($this->getProjectHistories() as $projectHistory) {
            $projectHistories[] = $projectHistory->toArray();
        }

        return $projectHistories;
    }

    public function getId(): ?string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(string $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getSnapshotId(): ?string
    {
        return $this->snapshotId;
    }

    public function setSnapshotId(string $snapshotId): void
    {
        $this->snapshotId = $snapshotId;
    }

    public function getCid(): string
    {
        return $this->cid;
    }

    public function setCid(string $cid): void
    {
        $this->cid = $cid;
    }

    public function getProjectHistories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->projectHistories;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection|ProjectHistory[] $projectHistories
     * @return Project
     */
    public function addProjectHistories(ArrayCollection $projectHistories): Project
    {
        foreach ($projectHistories as $projectHistory) {
            if (! $this->projectHistories->contains($projectHistory)) {
                $this->projectHistories->add($projectHistory);
                $projectHistory->setProject($this);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection|ProjectHistory[] $projectHistories
     * @return Project
     */
    public function removeProjectHistories(ArrayCollection $projectHistories): Project
    {
        foreach ($projectHistories as $projectHistory) {
            if ($this->projectHistories->contains($projectHistory)) {
                $this->projectHistories->remove($projectHistory);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use DateTime;
use DateTimeInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class ProjectHistory
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @var string
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column()
     * @var string
     */
    private $function;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @var Datetime
     */
    private $modifyDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @var string
     */
    private $modifyUserId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="projectHistories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_cid", referencedColumnName="cid")
     * @var Project
     */
    private $project;

    public function toArray(): array
    {
        return [
            'id'           => $this->getId(),
            'projectCid'   => $this->getProjectCid(),
            'function'     => $this->getFunction(),
            'modifyDate'   => $this->getModifyDateAsString(),
            'modifyUserId' => $this->getModifyUserId(),
        ];
    }

    public function getModifyDateAsString(): string
    {
        if (null === $this->getModifyDate()) {
            return '';
        }

        return $this->getModifyDate()->format(DateTimeInterface::ATOM);
    }

    public function getProjectCid(): ?string
    {
        if (null !== $this->getProject()) {
            return $this->getProject()->getCid();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function getId(): ?string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(string $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getFunction(): string
    {
        return $this->function;
    }

    public function setFunction($function): void
    {
        $this->function = $function;
    }

    public function getModifyDate(): DateTime
    {
        return $this->modifyDate;
    }

    public function setModifyDate(DateTime $modifyDate): void
    {
        $this->modifyDate = $modifyDate;
    }

    public function getModifyUserId(): string
    {
        return $this->modifyUserId;
    }

    public function setModifyUserId(string $modifyUserId): void
    {
        $this->modifyUserId = $modifyUserId;
    }

    public function getProject(): ?Project
    {
        return $this->project;
    }

    public function setProject(Project $project): void
    {
        $this->project = $project;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Let me know, if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usualy if you need to make such things, I mean reference by non-primary key, you have problem with the design. The first thing I thought about when reading your question is [Event Soursing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html). There is good implimentation of ES for PHP - [prooph](http://getprooph.org/). Unfortunately it's not trivial to refactor existed project to ES, but maybe it helps you to understand better the conception of history changes and snapshots.

According to the current situation I can say that It's not the purpose of `Project` to be a snapshot. You can modify the model and create `ProjectSnapshot` entity with relation to `Project`, then `ProjectHistory` will be related to `ProjectSnapshot`. Also I don't recommend you to store any associations (and foreign keys) in the snapshots, instead save only idenfiers of the related entities. Pay attention to the [loggable extension](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/loggable.md), may be it will be usefull.

Comment: These are excellent resources, thank you. The final solution might not be the same in all situations and therefore discussable. But either event sourcing or loggable might work in my case, which is why I accept this answer.